# Quotation marks

Tags: typography

I have problem with my Latex document, the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is "test". And another 'test'
\end{document}
```

results with this:

[image]

Is it possible to make something that will affect the whole document so that the quotation marks looks like this:

[image]

I know I can use `\lq` and `\rq` commands, but I have a huge document and I would really like to avoid going through it all. If there is some kind of directive that would affect the wole document to use opening and closing quotations?

Comment: just replace the starting with ***``test''*** and ***`test'*** respectively.

Comment: There is one problem: LaTeX does not know which `"` opens and which closes, hence you need to provide at least that piece of information (and as Raaja mentioned, using the TeX quotes would be an easy way to do so).

Comment: but then I still have to go through the whole document, and manually replace every occurence... I would like to avoid that.. it is the same as if I used \lq and \rq

Comment: @Amaja you can use `find` and `replace` option, which is a stock in almost all the text editors ;) I hope it helps.

Comment: I know.. but the document I'm working consist of hundreds of external .tex files.. I need to go over all of them.. and some sentences within quotations are complex in terms of characters, so I'm not sure which regex will properly fit in.. I was looking for elegant solution for example some package that will only be included in the preabule and will affect the whole document without the need for search and replace...

Comment: Nonetheless, an *editor* solution will be easier and preferable in all ways to a *LaTeX* solution.  You should be able to write a macro with most editors to handle 2 at a time, and thus not get out of sequence (except for lone apostrophes).

Comment: Then again, you could just set your document in `\ttfamily`...just kidding.

Comment: You have tagged the question with `csquotes` and that package can help a lot. Try `\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}`, though I usually prefer `\enquote{foo}` to `"foo"` with `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`.

Comment: You can probably get most of the way there by globally changing `<space>"` to `<space>`` ` and `"<space>` to `''<space>`(and possibly also `",` and `".` depending on whether your punctuation goes inside or outside the quotes.) Then mop up the remainder manually.

Comment: " I'm working consist of hundreds of external .tex files." A good programmer's editor will make global changes to hundreds of files with just one command - you don't have to open, change and close each file yourseif!

Comment: You don't even need an editor, just run `find -name *.tex` and run it through `sed` in whatever way you prefer ... if you're confident in your regex.

Answer (score 10):

You can try for the double quotes the `csquotes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
This is "test". 

\end{document}
```

But it will only work if there are always pairs of double quotes, if they are correctly nested with respect to tex groups, and if you don't use quotes for other purposes (e.g. to quote spaces in a file name). In large documents it almost never runs without error from the beginning.

For single quotes there is nothing similar. `csquotes` will not allow you (for good reasons) to set `'` as a quote sign. The main problem here is that quite probably you are using it as apostroph in various places too -- see above the `don't` in my text.

Answer (score 5):

I earlier joked about just setting the document in `\ttfamily`.  But that raised the possibility of making `"` active and just setting that glyph in the symmetric `\texttt` style.

EDITED to also work for single quote while at the same time preserving its behavior as a superscript prime in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\catcode`'=\active %
\catcode`"=\active %
\makeatletter
\def'{\ifmmode\def\qnxt{\catcode`'=12 ^\bgroup\prim@s}%
      \else\def\qnxt{\textquotesingle}\fi\qnxt}
\makeatother
\def"{\textquotedbl}
\begin{document}
This is "test". And another 'test'.

$x'$ and $x''$ and $x'''$.

And this is a final 'test'.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svq"
\catcode`"=\active
\def"{\texttt{\svq}}
\begin{document}
This is a "test" of active "quotes."
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's *quite* ugly isn't it? :P But a very very nice work around +1 :)

Comment: @Au101 The same cannot be easily done for the single quote because of its use as a superscript prime in math mode.

Comment: @Au101...but I somehow managed to do it anyway.

Comment: Why not just use the standard `` and ‘’ for double quotes and ` and ‘ for single quotes?

Comment: @HerbSchulz Because for any given instance, I don't know whether it is the left or the right one.  Thus, the "unisex" quotes seems the only alternative.  As I told the OP in comments, best solution is for him to edit his source and fix it.